# What version of Microsoft Exchange am I running?

Tags: email, exchange

I recently joined a company where nobody knows what's going on with the email server. I'm trying to fix and tidy things but I need to know which version of Exchange we are running. I have access to the Outlook Web App but it doesn't list the version anywhere. It looks like this:

[image]

Any idas what version it is?

Comment: You tel us, click `Copyright` and/or `Help`, provide us that information.

Answer (score 0):

It's Exchange 2010, for the exact version click on 'About':

[image]

14.0 - Exchange 2010 RTM

14.1 - SP1

14.2 - SP2

14.3 - SP3